# When is it not recommended to use ReadyBoost in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, performance, readyboost

I've read lots of questions here in SU about ReadyBoost and that it does help low-end machines.  However, there is nothing definitive about the upper limit -- when is using ReadyBoost negligible (or even detrimental)?

My laptop runs on Windows Vista Home Premium 32-bit, with 3GB RAM, and it has a slot for SD cards.  I'd like to know if I'd benefit from ReadyBoost significantly, or if there would be no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this article : [Microsoft Windows Vista & ReadyBoost: Does it Make a Difference?](http://www.pcstats.com/articleview.cfm?articleID=2160)
This article contains performance tests that try to answer this question.

It says:

> What many people failed to realized is
>   that newer PCs, with quick hard drives
>   like the Western Digital Raptor (for
>   example) don't necessarily see the
>   same impact from ReadyBoost as first
>   thought. It's really only older
>   computers, which have been upgraded to
>   Microsoft Windows Vista but barely
>   meet the minimum operating system
>   requirements, that potentially benefit
>   from ReadyBoost.
>
> ReadyBoost makes a bit of a difference
>   when the system has 512MB of memory,
>   but it's nothing to write home about.
>   If you're at the minimum end of PC
>   infrastructure, ReadyBoost may make
>   things a bit more bearable but you'd
>   be better off upgrading system memory
>   to at least 1GB RAM.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fast machine and/or the ready boost drive is slower.

I have no proof if it is Windows or the Intel driver, but I tried [Intel Turbo Memory](http://www.intel.com/design/flash/nand/turbomemory/index.htm) in my laptop when it first came out, which gives 512MB of ReadyBoost and 512MB of ReadyDrive, however my laptop kept BSODing and I was told it is because the memory was to slow to keep up - My laptop specs are T9300 cpu, 4GB DDR2 800 speed.

I think Readyboost works better, but personally, I wouldn't use it - I would rather spend the money on a RAM upgrade and as my machine never goes above 80% memory (when im in full swing of things) I don't really think I would benefit.

Comment: When did you fill up the 4GB of RAM? I'm not sure Windows would use ReadyBoost unless it ran out of usable RAM.

Comment: I never ran out of 4GB, I have only come close - that is why I took out my Turbo Memory - The R stands for Random, and I can *only* guess that some of it was being used even when it wasn't needed... I was getting BSOD at random, sometimes within seconds of booting and other times after a few minutes, but the BSOD was always the same driver... from the Turbo Memory - It means that the problem could be just the Intel drivers, however I still say just buy more memory rather than use this tech... If you have a need for over 4GB, the chances are you can afford more memory

Comment: The R in Turbo? :)

Comment: Ahh! +1 I didn't explain well at all-tried to say that if you have 2GB of memory, and then 1GB of Ready Boost - then you have an application requiring 1GB of memory, your machine has a total of 3GB and it is assigned randomly - maybe half on the ReadyBoost device and half in memory... My point is that if you never exceed your memory, why use a slower device for extra (and isn't that what page file is for :S )... Again, I have no proof that this is how it works, but as I have not exceeded 4GB of memory, I don't see the need for this tech and for laptops with less, I would rather buy memory.

Answer (score 1):

The thing about RAM is that it is extremely fast! Way faster than a harddrive is when feeding the CPU data. This is why RAM was invented. (ram 6gb/s vs disk 60/90MB/s) (aprox.)

However, when there is RAM available, Readyboost will not do you much good. When there is no RAM available, readyboost might improve the responsiveness of your machine, but I doubt it will be any faster.

If you have three GB of RAM. I do not think readyboost will change your performance, not even a bit. SD and USB drives still are much slower than RAM.

So to answer your question. It is never recommended to use Readyboost unless you are totally out of RAM.

Comment: It is never recommended? Why not? It has no detrimental impact...

Comment: Indeed, you answered the question. It has no XXX impact. Why bother! Would you attach your vacuumcleaner to your PC if I said it would run just the same?

Comment: readyboost can still help boot time even of you have more RAM than you need